# Virtual Hosting in Tomcat and Xampp

Tags: apache, tomcat, xampp

We have windows based XAMPP webserver which has built-in tomcat server. I have deployed an app on tomcat and having issue while mapping url to application.
Xampp (80,443) and tomcat (9091,9093) are running on different ports. I have configured server.xml but when I am trying to access mapped url, its not reachable. I checked in network tab on browser inspector it is trying to reach on server's port 80.
Below is configuration part from server.xml

[image]

Comment: You should add lot of more details: `server.xml`, configuration of URL mapping, URL you input in the browser, exact error messages, ...

Comment: Error: HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found. URL is reaching to Xampp port 80/443 instead of tomcat port 9091/9093

Comment: Request URL: http://myapp.com/
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 404 Not Found
Remote Address: **.***.**.***:80
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Comment: FYI never post text as an image.  A copy-paste is quite easy (and then use icon `{}` in the editor to make it formatted as code).

Comment: You have both Apache httpd and Apache Tomcat.  If you ask for `http://SOMETHING` is will go to port 80.  `https://SOMETHING` goes to port 443.  These are defaults.  And Apache httpd will answer these requets.  To talk directly to Tomcat, you have to force the port like so: `http://SOMETHING:9091`.  I guessed 9091 is http, 9093 is https, but you do not show this config.